# update-rc.d squid3 init.d init weirdness

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, squid

`sudo service squid3 status` works, implying `squid` is in upstart.
However a listing of services using

```
sudo service --status-all
```

does not show `squid`. Neither does

```
sudo update-rc.d squid3 defaults
```

work (gives an error saying `update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/squid3: file does not exist`).

On doing some research I found that:

1. `squid3.conf` is in `/etc/init`
2. But not in `/etc/init.d`
3. Not listed in any runlevels `/etc/rc?.d`

My objective is to not have `squid` start at runtime. I was hoping to do this using upstart. Without this my only option is to comment out the run level line: start [2345l]. Correct?

Also why this weirdness? Any thoughts, explanations?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: please check here link, there init script -> http://www.mediacomptech.com/2013/12/server-setting-etcinitdsquid-on-squid3.html

Answer (score 1):

To prevent an `upstart` from starting automatically during boot, best would be to create a file as follows.

```
echo "manual" >> /etc/init/squid3.override
```

This will disable autostart, but you still can start the job manually. For more information about the configuration please see [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting).

Concerning the `service --status-all` command, this only shows the `SysV` init scripts located in `/etc/init.d`.
For `upstart` related jobs, you might want to have a look at the `initctl` command. E.g.

```
initctl list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `update-rc.d squid3 disable`. You will get a warning about the init script not existing, but it will still disable the upstart job perfectly.

Comment: I doubt that `update-rc.d` will configure the `upstart` jobs in a correct way.

Comment: `update-rc.d` works perfectly fine for Upstart, sysvinit, and systemd on modern Debian based distros